# Styling a shapefile obtained from S-57 data

Tags: geoserver, layers, sld, s-57

I have downloaded S-57 data for a particular region and intend to publish this as a layer in GeoServer. To do this I used the ogr2ogr converter utility to convert S-57 data to a series of shapefiles (one for each feature).

The feature I am interested in is the Depth Contours feature(DEPCNT). I uploaded the shapefile corresponding to this feature in GeoServer and published it as a layer.

I am now able to see the Contours in the layer Preview. By looking up the attribute list for the layer I can see that the value of depth along contours is stored in the VALDCO(type double) field in meters. I am trying to create an SLD style by drawing the lines along with text labels, with the VALDCO attribute providing the value for the text label. I did this as follows:

```
   <LineSymbolizer>
      <Stroke>
        <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
      </Stroke>
    </LineSymbolizer>
     <TextSymbolizer>
       <Label>
         <ogc:PropertyName>VALDCO</ogc:PropertyName>
       </Label>
       <LabelPlacement>
         <LinePlacement />
       </LabelPlacement>
```

I am unable to see any text label with this property value. Is there anything wrong with the way I have done the styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct (assuming you have closed the TextSymbolizer somewhere lower down), but is a fairly minimal style. It is possible that GeoServer is unable to find a good place to draw any of your labels if the lines are very complex and close together, try zooming in and see if any labels appear. Alternatively you might apply a filter to just the "important" contours (say 100s or 50s) and label just those or give them a higher priority.

You could look at the example provided on [this page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html) (ignore the transform since you already have contour lines).

```
        <TextSymbolizer>
          <Label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
          </Label>
          <Font>
            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
          </Font>
          <LabelPlacement>
            <LinePlacement/>
          </LabelPlacement>
          <Halo>
            <Radius>
              <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
            </Radius>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Halo>
          <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
          </Fill>
          <Priority>2000</Priority>
          <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
          <VendorOption name="repeat">100</VendorOption>
          <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
          <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
        </TextSymbolizer>
```